# csv to json, json key are incorrect

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function

```
  generateArrayFromCSV(data, delimiter = ',') {
    const titles = data.slice(0, data.indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);
    return data
        .slice(data.indexOf('\n') + 1)
        .split('\n')
        .map(v => {
            const values = v.split(delimiter);
            return titles.reduce(
                (obj, title, index) => ((obj[title] = values[index]), obj),
                {}
            );
        });
  };
```

I input the following code (you need to JSON PARSE this )

```
generateArrayFromCSV(`"id","longitude","latitude","height","heading","pitch","roll"
"e33ccb1d-bd23-4da7-a006-caa3b998b5a0",139.60705614794117,35.713942413120606,20,0,0,0
"40ddec13-4888-48be-8382-6761b826f2f2",139.60697489329232,35.71356021532803,20,0,0,0
"396c841c-99a2-49ea-928f-dd26'`)
```

Now, it looks ok, when I load a csv into it, and get the returned value in the console, it looks correct.

The problem is, even if in the console my object appear like this

```
{"id": ""e33ccb1d-bd23-4da7-a006-caa3b998b5a0"", "longitude": "139.60705614794117", "latitude": "35.713942413120606"}
```

to actually access my object, I need to do the following

```
temp1["\"heading\""]
```

because there is actually those `\"key\"` everywhere

but I don't see a good way to remove them

I tried

```
        (obj, title, index) => {title = title.replace('\"', ''); return ((obj[title] = values[index]), obj); },
```

but it remove only one `\` (so it becomes like this)

[image]

Comment: Is it not `temp1["heading"]` ? and within your returned object, there isn't a key heading

Comment: no, every value is accessible with the \", but not without, in the console, if I hover a key, they do show the "\"heading\"", but only if I hover

Comment: It's a parsing problem. Remove the " at le end of your key.

Comment: try
...
(obj, title, index) => {title = title.replace(/"/g, ''); return ((obj[title] = values[index]), obj); }...

Comment: Can you just show the input sample?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra it works with your solution, thanks

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan will edit just 2 min

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan up there

Comment: Your input data seems dirty... why you have extra pairs of quotes around the UUID? Why every property ends with `"`? And why in your sample the single quote after `"396c841c-99a2-49ea-928f-dd26'`?

Comment: it is coming from a FileReader, of a normal csv

Comment: https://pastebin.com/huPsPTtj

Comment: ArshpreetWadehra got it right, You have unescaped quotes (representing Strings) inside a Template literal ` `. You need to get rid of the double quotes.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your CVS titles are wrapped in quotes? You could try to fix the problem at its source... Just blindly removing (instead of escaping?) double quotes is poor-man's code... `Number of " quotes` is a valid Title if you ask me :)